# Transfer a pandas data table to text file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data set:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'ID': ['>H97', '>H80','>H85','>H91','>H91094'],
      'Sequence': ['GGAGTCGG','GAGGCTTAGTCCAG','GAAGCCTTCGGAGA', 'CTGTGCAGCCT', 'GCCTGGTCCAGCCT']}


df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

the data set looks like this:

```
>>> df
        ID        Sequence
0     >H97        GGAGTCGG
1     >H80        GAGGCTTAGTCCAG
2     >H85        GAAGCCTTCGGAGA
3     >H91        CTGTGCAGCCT
4     >H91094     GCCTGGTCCAGCCT
```

I want to write to an **output .txt file** so that the file looks like:

```
>H97 
GGAGTCGG
>H80
GAGGCTTAGTCCAG
>H85        
GAAGCCTTCGGAGA
>H91        
CTGTGCAGCCT
>H91094
GCCTGGTCCAGCCT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\n` as the delimiter:

```
df.to_csv("test.txt", header=False, index=False, sep = "\n")
```

Out:

```
>H97
GGAGTCGG
>H80
GAGGCTTAGTCCAG
>H85
GAAGCCTTCGGAGA
>H91
CTGTGCAGCCT
>H91094
GCCTGGTCCAGCCT
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you intend to use it afterwards but that text file might be fairly useless if you want to load that DataFrame again. Writing it into a simple TXT file may be not structured enough.

Why don't you save it as CSV file? This way you will be able to read it as such again.

```
df.to_csv("out.csv")
```

and then you can load it

```
df = pandas.read_csv("out.csv")
```

Comment: This is unrelated to OP's question